# Xamarin linphone video call

Tags: xamarin, video, linphone

I try to set linphone on Xamarin Shared Project; for audio calls is simple, but for video calls I not be able to set properly the environment.
In particular, from documentation, I've to set an instance of AndroidVideoWindowImpl for mediastreamer settings, but this class not exists in the imported packages mediastreamer_base and mediastreamer_voip. 
I try to set a SurfaceView through LinphoneCore method setNativeVideoWindowId, but the app crashes with the follow error

```
[Linphone] android_display_init 0xe677a8c8 0xd28b3de0
[Linphone] no such method on filter MSAndroidDisplay, fid=16387 method index=1
[Linphone] RtpSession [0xd1831400] error sending [rtp] packet [0xef0c5b60] to no-addr: Destination address required [89]
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0xd26e2f10
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]     from void md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(android.view.View)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75f86f80 self=0xf53b6500
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | sysTid=20664 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf76cab34
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4510 stm=906 core=2 HZ=100
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | stack=0xff0a7000-0xff0a9000 stackSize=8MB
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #00 pc 0035aee7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+126)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #01 pc 0033ba6b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+138)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #02 pc 0024e203  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+750)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #03 pc 0024e90b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+62)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #04 pc 0033c5bf  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread13DecodeJObjectEP8_jobject+174)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #05 pc 000ffc0f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE.constprop.95+890)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #06 pc 001120c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI12NewGlobalRefEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobject+368)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #07 pc 00085f41  /data/app/org.linphone.xamarin-1/lib/arm/libmediastreamer_voip.so (???)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #08 pc 000825b3  /data/app/org.linphone.xamarin-1/lib/arm/libmediastreamer_voip.so (???)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #09 pc 00081ee3  /data/app/org.linphone.xamarin-1/lib/arm/libmediastreamer_voip.so (video_stream_start_from_io+342)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #10 pc 002e8167  /data/app/org.linphone.xamarin-1/lib/arm/liblinphone.so (linphone_call_start_media_streams+3614)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #11 pc 002d527f  /data/app/org.linphone.xamarin-1/lib/arm/liblinphone.so (linphone_call_update_streams+430)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #12 pc 002ea7ab  /data/app/org.linphone.xamarin-1/lib/arm/liblinphone.so (linphone_call_accept_with_params+474)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   native: #13 pc 00004fb8   (???)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.n_onClick(Native method)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at md5270abb39e60627f0f200893b490a1ade.ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.onClick(ButtonRenderer_ButtonClickListener.java:30)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5217)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21342)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
[art] art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] 
[Linphone] RtpSession [0xd1831400] error sending [rtp] packet [0xef0c7ca0] to no-addr: Destination address required [89]
```

Anyone that have the same problems?
Thanks.

Comment: `Org.Linphone.Mediastream.Video.AndroidVideoWindowImpl`

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply. Have you try this solution? I don't find this namespace.

Comment: What binding are you using for Linphone?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. I Have included the .so libraries for each platform and use the LinphoneWrapper file; now I would to compile linphone submodules, but obtain always an error Could NOT find MbedTLS (missing:  MBEDTLS_LIBRARIES), even if it is installed and included in PATH environment variable.

Comment: Ah, I'm assuming when you say "LinphoneWrapper file", you mean the C# wrapper? I created a Android binding library for the Android Linphone Java SDK and used it that way as the C# wrapper does not supply items like `AndroidVideoWindowImpl`. You could alway write the Android implementations in Xamarin.Android/C# if you want.

Comment: Sorry I mean C# wrapper. However, are you able to make video with Linphone and xamarin? Because your both explanations are wrong for me

Comment: Video? Yes, because I used the Java SDK and created a Xamarin.Andriod Binding Library project for it.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your reply and explanation, I will try it.

Comment: I've compiled linphone libraries & co, but when I link the .so files in a Xamarin Project(Shared, Binding Project ecc) I don't know how link and wrapper of methods. For example, if I want the AndroidVideoWindowImpl constructor method, I write [DllImport("mediastreamer_voip", EntryPoint = "AndroidVideoWindowImpl")]
        public static extern IntPtr AndroidVideoWindowImpl(Android.Views.SurfaceView renderingSurface, Android.Views.SurfaceView previewSurface); but I obtain always an EntryNotFoundException.

Comment: ? `AndroidVideoWindowImpl` is written in the Java in the `.arr`